# Replacing a ceiling register cover

Tags: central-heating

I was replacing an old ceiling register cover in my house but I found the screw hole on one side of the opening is kind of loose. Is there a way to patch up the mount point so the cover is fully supported?

Comment: Does the cover attach to the register, or just into the drywall?  What is it made of (wood, metal, plastic?)

Comment: A picture might help.  Also a better description of the problem might be good.  Is the hole for the screw that holds up the grate too big for the screw? Is the screw into just drywall? Is there a drywall anchor for the screw to go into?

Answer (score 2):

Break the (non-ignition) end of a balsa-wood kitchen matchstick into the screw hole, then thread the screw into the hole. This will compress the matchstick and provide a snug fit for the screw.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably squirt a bit of caulking or liquid nails in the hole to help tighten it up.  Let it dry before putting the register back up.